# Ventilating a flat roof

Tags: hvac, waterproofing, ventilation, exhaust-fan, roofing

My ensuite bathroom has a major humidity problem. I took the fan out (it's one of those combo heat lamp + light + fan units) expecting the fan to be broken, but found another problem - it's just venting into a little box of rafters, with no path to outside. I'm no HVAC expert but it feels like the fan isn't going to do its best work if it's blowing into an effectively sealed cavity the size of a shoebox.

I think I've got two options to ventilate this ceiling space - I can go sideways, carefuly putting a hole through all of the rafters, put a duct through and have a vent on the outside wall. Advantage: less risk of leaks. Disadvantage: huge job, I'd end up with a pretty low diameter duct because I don't  want huge holes in my rafters. I don't like this idea much.

The option I'm more interested in is going up, and venting to the outside (through a mushroom vent, a whirlybird or something else) directly above the indoor fan. I asked a roofing contractor about this and he wasn't very keen on the idea - I have a flat roof (bituminous flashing over what I assume is a concrete deck). He was pretty confident I'd have leaks if he put anything in. I'm a bit perplexed by this because - a few meters away on the roof - there are some existing vents, presumably for the plumbing stack / sewer. Here's a [pic](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM9_kI_De2qN6DVwbwEDN5yaUjhQyUQuYaklgQOOnCo98-Xd6hQ0xfm7kp0Zd0l9g?key=dXV6dmNBUlFtTDJxNHptOU1DaTEwVlVPNUpxY0RB). I belive the extra height on these is because there's meant to be a layer of solid foam insulation + a pebble ballast on the roof (I thought perhaps the original owner decided to do batts in the ceiling space instead, but on my most recent foray I noticed the ceiling space is very empty).

Am I right to think an additional bit of venting will help here? Should I go for something passive, and hope the interior fan provides enough force, or should I get a powered unit on the outside too and try to run it off the same circuit as the fan so they come on together? Am I mad to try and put something like [this](https://thelightingoutlet.com.au/products/550m-h-ventair-roof-exhaust-fan-centrifugal-150mm-fan0529?variant=31756288426026&currency=AUD) on a flat roof?

I'm in Australia, which I mention because we have heat and rain but never snow.

Comment: Don't cut your rafters, they are structural. Notice in the picture, the slope of the roof and the location of the vents, they are at the peak, the top of the slope (even 'flat' roofs have some slope to direct the water to the drains). If your vents are in a low area, this might be the reason for your roofers comments. Raising the height of the protruding part won't help much.

Comment: What about the *usual obvious alternative* to cutting holes in a bunch of rafters, namely, running *between* them, parallel to them?

Comment: Shoot, sorry - that's what I was trying to describe. There are large beams, which I would leave untouched, and smaller cross-members that divide the open space up into little pockets. Getting to an outside eave would require drilling through a heap of these little crossmember guys.

I'll try to grab a photo, I'm definitely using the wrong words for half of these things.